# Git submodule update --init shows changes need to be committed

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a repo with a submodule. After cloning the repo, and running `git submodule update --init --recursive`

I cd into the submodule and a git status shows :

```
*:sfPropelORMPlugin eyellott$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   deleted:    .gitignore
#   deleted:    .gitmodules
#   deleted:    .travis.yml
#   deleted:    LICENSE
#   deleted:    LICENSE.Propel
#   deleted:    LICENSE.phing
#   deleted:    README.md
#   deleted:    config/autoload.yml
#   deleted:    config/installer.php
#   deleted:    config/sfPropelORMPluginConfiguration.class.php
#   deleted:    config/skeleton/config/databases.yml
#   deleted:    config..
...
```

How can a fresh clone of a repo and a submodule update result in changes that need to be committed?

Answer (score 0):

There were issues writing to that folder? Check permissions?